# Query para juntar uma coluna a partir de outra

Tags: mysql, sql, query, select

Tenho tentado sem sucesso obter um resultado.

Tenho a tabela com a informação de Login e Logout seguinte:

```
|Group        |User    |EventDate              |Event        |Camp
------------------------
|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:36:04    |LOGIN        |AUTENTI1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:38:18    |LOGOUT       |AUTENTI1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:38:28    |LOGIN        |AUTENTI1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:39:21    |LOGOUT       |AUTENTI1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:41:46    |LOGIN        |EVOL1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 13:09:53    |LOGOUT       |EVOL1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 13:11:19    |LOGIN        |EVOL1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 13:39:49    |LOGOUT       |EVOL1
```

Como faço para obter o Login e Logout na mesma linha separado por campanha.

```
|Group        |User    |Login                  |LogOut               |Camp
--------
|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:36:04    |2014-07-07 10:38:18  |AUTENTI1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:38:28    |2014-07-07 10:39:21  |AUTENTI1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 10:41:46    |2014-07-07 13:09:53  |EVOL1

|Evolution    |1012    |2014-07-07 13:11:19    |2014-07-07 13:39:49  |EVOL1
```

Comment: O que seria "group" e "camp"?

Comment: Olá, Group uma equipa ao qual pertence o user, pode-se ignorar, e Camp, onde o user inseriu uma linha quando fez login, e uma outra quando fez logout.
O sistema insere uma nova linha sempre que á uma interação do user indicando, coloca a data/hora e se é login ou logout, não posso mudar isso, mas preciso obter uma listagem por campanha e por user da hora do login numa coluna e logout noutra coluna.

Comment: Tenho uma informação que esta na mesma coluna em linhas separadas, que preciso transformar numa linha e colunas diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que assim deva funcionar, utilizei somente funções genéricas pois não foi especificado qual SGDB está usando

```
SELECT
  A.group,
  A.user,
  A.eventdate as login,
  (SELECT 
      B.eventdate
   FROM 
      TABELA B 
   WHERE 
      B.event = 'LOGOUT' AND
      B.user = A.user AND 
      B.group = A.group AND 
      B.camp = A.camp AND 
      B.eventdate > A.eventdate
   LIMIT 1) as logout,
  A.camp
FROM
  TABELA A
WHERE
  A.event = 'LOGIN'
```

Comment: Se o BD suportar o uso de CASE e uma função de agrupamento pode ser outra solução , informe o BD @Vitor Freitas

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado.
Ja vou testar e darei o feedback. O servidor é mySql 5.1.

Comment: @VitorFreitas Ajustei para MySQL

Comment: Sucesso, muito, muito obrigado a vocês.

Comment: @VitorFreitas Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou é assinalando a melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil pra todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.    Por favor, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/7210)